# how to mimic partial view in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on an Asp.net website (it's been awhile) coming from an MVC background. How would I mimic partial views in Asp.net? Do I use web user controls or web part zones, or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET is actually the base engine for both ASP.NET Webforms and ASP.NET MVC.

If you're used to MVC then you should really use ASP.NET MVC, where Partial Views are first class citizens.

### Use ASP.NET MVC

To use one, you simply create a new MVC project, right click on the shared folder in the View folder, and select Add New View. From there you can select Partial View.

### If you have to use Webforms

If you're stuck with webforms, then you use UserControls. The webforms model doesn't really translate well to the MVC paradigm, but UserControls are the closest things.

I think webparts are for Sharepoint only... ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

User Controls are the ASP.NET WebForms equal of ASP.NET MVC Partial Views.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using ASP.NET webforms and not ASP.NET MVC or this wouldn't be an issue.  In webforms you can use UserControls (.ascx) to achieve a similar result.

One of the advantages of using user controls is you can interact directly with the details of the user control by exposing public properties and methods in the user control itself. You can make the user control have a lot of flexibility and have much of it's functionality defined by pure markup as well.

With partial views in MVC this is not really possible.  I can't really think of anything you can't do with a user control that you can with a partial view in MVC.  On the flip side there is ton of stuff a partial view can't do that a user control can.

Example of using a user control in a webforms project.

First add a reference to your user control at top of aspx page:

```
<%@ Register Src="UserControls/PersonSearch.ascx" TagName="PersonSearch" 
    TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```

Then when you want to use it:

```
<uc1:PersonSearch hid="ucPersonSearch" runat="server">
</uc1:PersonSearch>
```

You can register events from you main page with the user control, expose properties, methods, etc...

For instance you could have a user control and register a notify event from your main page with the user control to get triggered once a person is selected.  The user control just has to know about checking to see if a delegate has been registered and call it.  This gives the container the ability to use the user control however it wants and leverage it's strength in unique ways.

It's more like a partial view on steroids but I 'partial' to user controls (pun intended) :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Web User Controls. As far as I can tell they offer the same functionality. Plus the MVC implementation in ASP.NET uses them for partial views as well.